# Xcode Leaks tool doesn't work

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory, ios, memory-leaks

I'm developing some iOS app with the latest Xcode. I'm currently interested in Xcode's Leaks tool.

And I used Leaks to run my app (which contains thousands of lines of code and is in no way memory safe). I ran my app and did all kinds of stuff on it. But Leaks just didn't report any leaking (as was in this screen shot http://d.pr/NKbF).

I then tried to use this set of codes to *simulate* some leaks:

```
int i = rand();
NSMutableString *leak = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d qwerty", i];
leak = NULL;
```

But again no leaks were reported.

Help... Anyone can help me? :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the Leaks instrument is *conservative*, in other words every issue it reports is very probably a leak, but it won't necessarily report every leak. That's thought to be better than the alternative, where it might report every leak but is likely to report things that aren't leaks too.

While I would have thought it unlikely, it is possible that it just missed your leak.

Comment: Thanks Graham! I'll try some other ways to *simulate* the leaks.

Answer (score 1):

the number 1 tool for finding leaks (and other issues) is the static analyzer. You use it by selecting "Build and Analyze" or shift-option-A. When it's done select build results and click the blue squares shown, then click again in the code window. You'll get a nice visual indication of just what is going wrong.

Leaks is useful but is more of a long term fine tuning tool. Analyser find the problems you made yourself, the ones that happen right now and every time your class gets used.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I just tried Analyser and it was indeed helpful. Though I'm still wondering why no leaking was reported in Leaks. It's just weird...

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using static analysis as an alternative to Instruments. Use both of them. They both find different kinds of bugs.